# Reporting Services conditionally hide fields

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report where I have about 5 fields right next to eachother that dont return data in about 90% of the reports. Is there a way to hide these fields if they are empty otherwise display them if they do contain data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress columns conditionally in the report designer in SSRS, by selecting the table column and editing the Visibility>Hidden property (in the Properties window) to be the suppression condition.

Note that if the suppression condition is False at any point in the report, the columns will be displayed throughout the whole report.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write VBScript in the RDL file to display the field if it is not Nothing and the like.